# Funding programs for mathematical research

Tags: soft-question, big-list, career, advice

In the USA, as far as I know, the main grants available to mathematicians are collected on the [NSF](https://www.nsf.gov/div/index.jsp?div=DMS) or the [AMS](http://www.ams.org/programs/programs) websites [please, correct me if this perception is inaccurate]. On the other hand, for European countries for example, the situation seems to be much more scattered. In addition to the various [ERC grants](https://erc.europa.eu/homepage), I would like to use this post to collect other specific funding programs that mathematicians may apply to (at the national or international level).

In fact, we could make the question more general and ask it *on a world-wide level*: **What funding programs are available supporting mathematical research and researchers?**
It would be nice to make this question community-wiki and possibly have an answer addressing each country in the world and one for multi/inter-national funding programs.

---

This question appeared in [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/189976/grants-accessible-to-italian-mathematicians) specifically for Italy, but I think it's very relevant in this generalized form for the MathOverflow community.

Comment: I love the optimism implicit in the big-list tag :-)

Comment: Is there a specific reason to stick to Europe?

Comment: @YCor Just that I'm personally interested in that; but, in fact, we could very well make the question more general and world-wide

Comment: @Kei I guess this would be of more general interest.

Comment: @YCor I agree. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Mathematics is for the optimists after all, right? :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it's asking for too big of a big list. There are thousands of funding mechanisms. The question will get a zillion answers and be forever on the front page as links die and are edited in years to come. It will inevitably fall out of date, like the old question about which software people find useful.

Answer (score 3):

[COST EU](https://www.cost.eu/) has grants for research in any area. They have funded pure mathematics research (by Rita Fioresi).

Answer (score 2):

Let me start the (hopefully long) list of answers by addressing the USA:

- **NSF**: (a) [Funding & Awards page](https://beta.nsf.gov/funding), (b) [Funding Search (division of mathematical sciences)](https://beta.nsf.gov/funding/opportunities?sort_bef_combine=nsf_funding_upcoming_due_dates_DESC&f%5B0%5D=division%3A43)
- **AMS**: [AMS programs page](http://www.ams.org/programs/programs), which for example leads to (a) [travel grants](http://www.ams.org/programs/travel-grants), (b) [many grants, prizes, and other opportunities](http://www.ams.org/opportunities), (c) [several fellowships](http://www.ams.org/programs/ams-fellowships/ams-fellowships).

---

This answer is CW, feel free to edit it to include more information.

Answer (score 2):

The Australian Research Council (https://www.arc.gov.au/
is the general funding body which funds grants for research in any area including in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

The [Irish Research Council](https://research.ie/) funds research in any area, by researchers at least one of whom is based in Ireland. They have funded pure mathematics research (by Spyridon Dendrinos.)